# Automated validation of XSD files, not XML instances

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am looking for a programmatic solution to this, not asking about a tool.

Given a directory of XSD files with imports to other XSD files in that directory,
I would like to verify all required imports are present and the XSDs are valid XML.

My current manual process:

- Open XML Spy
- Start a new project
- Add XSD files
- 'Validate XML' on all XSD files.

This gives error messages if there are issues or missing files.

How files are imported:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="Other.xsd" namespace="Foo"/>
```

I'm looking for an automated way to achieve this, preferably without the overhead of XML Spy, so that this can be integrated in an automated test.

This is not about validation XML instances based on those XSD files, only about validating the XSD files and their dependencies.

Comment: On what platform? Both Java and .NET have XSD (at least 1.0) support, so there it is simply a task of parsing/compiling your schema set and collecting any parsing/compilation warnings/errors to see whether there any problems. An example for .NET is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xmlschemaset-for-schema-compilation#compiling-schemas

Comment: Can you add that as an answer to accept? Sounds like the Compile() step would give me the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the platform your are on, on .NET (with XSD 1.0) you have good support for checking schemas with `XmlSchemaSet` by loading/compiling them and checking for any warnings or errors, details are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xmlschemaset-for-schema-compilation#compiling-schemas.

I think with Java there are different APIs but somehow similar functionality available.